# Does libapache-mod-deflate cache compressed result?

Tags: apache-2.2, cache, mod-deflate

I got some json files to be served by apache httpd and their size are pretty big. (~100KiB)
So I put mod_deflate into httpd server and applied to application/javascript mime type.

I think mod_deflate may burn more CPU powers to run gzip compression. Thus, if mod_deflate has no cache strategy for compressed contents, then 'Apache CPU Load' graph must be increased as Apache Bytes / Apache Requests increases.

But cacti graph shows different result from my prediction. I adopted mod_deflate at about Tue 13:00, CPU Load went up sometimes, but it falls right after.

My Question is : does mod_deflate has its own cache strategy?

[image: Apache httpd cacti graphs]